# cant read files from resources

Tags: java, tomcat

Im trying to read files(xml, images) from src/main/resources. But it doesnt work.My resources folder is Source folder. For example, when i m trying to read log4j.xml tomcat looking for it in C:/bin... And i also cant read images from resources. I can read it only from webapp. I ve read, that tomcat automatically replace files from resources to webinf, but i think that it doesnt work in my case.
Please, help. I dont have any idea.[image: Proof, that it doesnt work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the png is added to the WEB-INF folder it wouldn't be accessible from the JSP page in your case.

On runtime a JSP page renders into a servlet that return HTML code in the response. Then a browser will parse your tag `<img src="/Pajero.png" ... />` and send a request onto YOUR_HOST/Pajero.png url to access the image and get the error code 404, because content of the `WEB-INF` folder is not accessible for a client side in a java web application.

Perhaps it will be better to place images on the webapp folder at your case.

Comment: Thank you!
And maybe you can help me once again: when i out log4j.xml to resources it works, but when tomcat is starting, i get message that he cant find log4j.xml in C:/bin. It works, i can wrie logs, but why he requires this file also  in C:/bin

Comment: @Slwvin_45, sorry, but I have no so much experience in Tomcat and I am not familiar with its logging system.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("log4j.xml").getFile());
```

You can use something like this to get resources from classpath.

Regards

Comment: I know. I ve read all of this anwers. But i think i it s not the right way. It should work automatically, if no, why folder resources exists and it`s Source folder.